# Configure all hosts, then create a list of the config for all hosts?

Tags: linux, configuration, ansible

I deployed a huge number of hosts with Ansible - which did work very nice. Each host got its individual settings and configuration.

Now I'd like to generate a config file for another system that uses these hosts. For it, I need for every host a part of the generated configuration (the one that configures the database).

Here is an example of the situation with two hosts having different configuration and the other system that uses a part of the Ansible-generated configuration:

**host1**

ansible configured dbA

**host2**

ansible configured dbQ

**The other system:**

host1 = dbA

host2 = dbQ

The values are computed differently (`dbQ` instead of `dbB` for `host2` for example) if it belongs in a different cluster and so on, making it unpractical to just read out host configuration from the `host_vars`.
I believe I would need to iterate over the hosts and let Ansible figure out the computed values for the variables like it would when deploying, but I do not know how to put that result in one template.

Please advise :)

Comment: Please try to reword your question, it is not clear what are you attempting to do. The inventory file resides in only one host (the one you execute `ansible` from), and the `[]` groupings can be nested.

Comment: the examples were not meant to represent inventory files. I wated to give the results for two example hosts, where ansible configured there databases based on host- and group-vars -- and an example for the file I'd like to generate.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly you might be able to do this using a combination of set_fact and/or a template that then loops through all the hosts.  For example, assuming you have a task defined something like this:

```
- name : Configure database
  command: /path/to/some/script {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ some_var }} {{ some_other_var }}
```

You could use set_fact to associate those values with the host in question:

```
- name: Stash the variables for later use
  set_fact:
    var_1 : {{ some_var }}
    var_2 : {{ some_other_var }}
    host_and_var : "{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{ some_var}}"
    etc.
```

Then when the time comes to create your configuration file you would have a template action or local_action that generates the configuration file.  The template would contain something along these lines:

```
{% for host in groups['some_host_group']|sort %}
{% if hostvars[host]["var_1"] is defined %}
{{ host }} = {{ hostvars[host]["var_1"] }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```